# Closing Bootstrap 4 modal pressing back button

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have a web app that shows modal windows in bootstrap 4.

I have found a code on the internet that works fine when it comes to closing modal windows by pressing the back button.

However, when there are nested modals, that is one modal over another, pressing back button closes both the parent and child modals. I want only the child modal to close and the parent modal to remain on.

Here is my current code:

```
function utils_createModalListener(modalId) {
    let $modal = $("#" + modalId);
    let openModals = []; // Array to keep track of open modals

    function showContent(contentId) {
        // Function to dynamically change the modal content
        $modal.find('.modal-content').html($('#' + contentId).html());
    }

    function historyListener(event) {
        if (openModals.length > 0) {
            // Close only the topmost modal
            var topModalId = openModals.pop();
            $("#" + topModalId).modal('hide');
        }
    }

    $modal.on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
        $modal.attr('aria-hidden', false);
        openModals.push(modalId); // Add the modal to the stack
        window.history.pushState({ modal: modalId }, "Modal title", document.location + '#' + modalId);

        window.addEventListener('popstate', historyListener, false);

        setTimeout(function () {
            $modal.focus();
        }, 1);
    });

    $modal.on('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
        $modal.attr('aria-hidden', true);

        if (window.history.state && window.history.state.modal === modalId) {
            history.go(-1);
        }

        window.removeEventListener('popstate', historyListener);
    });

    // Handle initial state when the page is loaded with a modal open
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (window.location.hash === '#' + modalId) {
            $modal.modal('show');
        }
    });

    // Example: Change modal content based on a trigger button click
    $('.change-content-button').on('click', function () {
        let contentId = $(this).data('content-id');
        showContent(contentId);
    });
}


utils_createModalListener('theplan');
utils_createModalListener('plan_record');
utils_createModalListener('plan_attendance');
utils_createModalListener('collaborate_modal');
```

In the code above, i have 4 modals: `theplan, plan_record, plan_attendance, collaborate_modal`

The parent is plan_record and the child is plan_attendance

Can anyone help me to see how I can fine tune the function to handled nested modals?

Thank you so much